# typography variant in the Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am a new material UI, I am trying to use `Typography`, if I don't use variant in the typography tag, it is fine

```
<div className="login-details">
  <Typography>{details ? details.email : "N/A"} |</Typography>

  <Button type="link" onClick={()=> document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("user.start_logout"))}>
              logout
            </Button>
</div>
```

[image: without variant]

if I use a variant like below, the UI is falling apart

```
<div className="login-details">
        <Typography variant="h2">{details ? details.email : "N/A"} |</Typography>

        <Button type="link" onClick={() => document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("user.start_logout"))}>
          logout
        </Button>
      </div>
```

[image: With variant]

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using a variant is equivalent to `variant="body1"`. Check your h2 style, particularly the line height and margins. Refer to [the documentation](https://mui.com/customization/typography/) on how to customise the default typography.

Comment: yes, because of line-height I got the issue, May I know how to add line-height in px in the customized theme

Comment: @KeerthiReddyYeruva Again, please read [the documentation](https://mui.com/customization/typography/#variants), it is explained exactly how to do that, with examples. For accessibility reasons I would recommend you use rem units for the font size, and not pixels.